# How to redirect to a url

Tags: go

I would like to show client another page after data has been collected from previous page. But I have trouble redirect the new URL on the server side. Here is my logic:

1. submit user input with POST action to server;
2. server run function saveChoice() to save user input into a database;
3. After user input is saved, server send a new URL to client;
4. By the time the client GET the new URL, server reads the database and get saved data out

And I am stuck on step 3 (here is an example of the flow):

```
type Stuff struct{
    List []string
}

func checkcheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sinfo := Stuff{
        List: some_slice
    }

    t, err := template.New("").Parse(tpl_ds)
    checkErr(err)
    err = r.ParseForm()
    checkErr(err)
    err = t.Execute(w, sinfo)
    checkErr(err)

    if r.Method == "POST" {
        saveChoice(r.Form["choices"])
        /* step 3: make user open another URL */
    }
}
```

And here is the template:

```
<html>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <form method="POST">
    {{range .List}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="{{.}}"> <span>{{.}}</span><br>
    {{end}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

May I know how I can redirect to a new page?

p.s. If I put URL on button, then server is not going to run saveChoice()

Comment: Actually the effective part is to add if r.Method=="GET" like Aruna said, which prevents the error of redirecting 2 pages

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The http status 303 is the appropriate response here. So redirect the request with it.

```
if r.Method == "POST" {
    saveChoice(r.Form["choices"])
    http.Redirect(w, r, newUrl, http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

And if your `newUrl` is supposed to return a proper html page to the browser, you don't need to use ajax. Use an html form.

```
<form action="/postHandler" method="post">
   {{range .List}}
    <input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="{{.}}"> <span>{{.}}</span><br>
   {{end}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice `action` of the form is defined as `/postHandler`. Put the name of the endpoint that runs your `saveChoice` function there.

So to avoid `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls` error you get use this code.

```
  func checkcheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
      sinfo := Stuff{
        List: some_slice
      }

      t, err := template.New("").Parse(tpl_ds)
      checkErr(err)
      err = r.ParseForm()
      checkErr(err)
      err = t.Execute(w, sinfo)
      checkErr(err)
    }

    if r.Method == "POST" {
        saveChoice(r.Form["choices"])
        http.Redirect(w, r, newUrl, http.StatusSeeOther)
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, the server attempts to render both the form and the redirected url which will result in mutiple calls to the response writer.

Comment: At first it shows an error so I have to do preventDefault on the button

Comment: Kyle please post the javascript/html code you use with this button as well.

Comment: Kyle if the newUrl is supposed to return a proper html page, don't use ajax. Just let the form submit. Then the redirection will work.

Comment: I tried without the code and still doesn't work. And if I let the button or form action to redirect before I have data uploaded to server, then saveChoice() won't run. Let me see if I can put more code on so you can take a look at details. Thanks for the helps!

Comment: Kyle, what is the url of the post request that runs `saveChoice`? Could you show the code that defines this endpoint?

Comment: If `saveChoice` is synchronous, that is it returns only after the data is saved in the database, and you put the correct url, the one I asked for above, as the `action` of the `form` (in place of `postHandler`), then this code should work.

Comment: saveChoice is a function to write a slice into a database. The function doesn't return any value nor redirect to another URL. In fact I'm keep getting the following error when I use redirect: http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Comment: kyle I am guessing thats your multiple `checkErr` function calls.

Comment: do you mean multiple checkcheck function? I have used redirect function in login page and no issue. But whenever I use redirect with template I always got this error. So I've been avoiding using redirect...don't know why it happens...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105983/discussion-between-aruna-herath-and-kyle).

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "html/template"
)

type data struct {
  List string
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", check)
}

func check(w http.ResponseWriter, r * http.Request) {
  if r.Method == "GET" {
    sinfo: = data {
      List: "Here is a list of the files Located with in",
    }

    var tpl_ds = "index.html"

    //t, err := template.New("").Parse(tpl_ds)
    t: = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(tpl_ds))

    r.ParseForm()
    t.Execute(w, sinfo)
  }

  if r.Method == "POST" {
    saveChoice(r.Form["choices"])
    http.Redirect(w, r, newUrl, http.StatusSeeOther)
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the entire question but it leads to the answer. I hope this helps.